# When trying to parse xml file why i'm getting no results at all?

Tags: c#, xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlParser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ParseAndDisplayXml(@"C:\Users\myxml\Documents\myxml.xml");  
        }

        private void ParseAndDisplayXml(string filename)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);
            var list = document.Root.Elements("rect")
                .Select(
                e => new
                {
                    Width = e.Attribute("width").ToString(),
                    Height = e.Attribute("height").ToString(),
                    X = e.Attribute("x").ToString()
                }
                );
            string result = "";
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                result += string.Format("Width--{0},Height--{1},X--{2}", item.Width, item.Height, item.X);


            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The format part of the xml i'm trying to parse is in the middle on the xml file:
The rect parts and the paths.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg"
   inkscape:export-filename="C:\Users\adili_000\Desktop\drawing.png"
   inkscape:export-xdpi="125"
   inkscape:export-ydpi="125">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="470.51389"
     inkscape:cy="692.09768"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid4172" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4155"
       width="45.714287"
       height="30"
       x="37.387959"
       y="115.30345" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4155-5"
       width="45.714287"
       height="30"
       x="91.899246"
       y="115.40621" />
    <rect
<path
       sodipodi:type="star"
       style="opacity:1;fill:#f1c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path4841"
       sodipodi:sides="8"
       sodipodi:cx="288.21429"
       sodipodi:cy="396.29076"
       sodipodi:r1="21.58555"
       sodipodi:r2="10.792775"
       sodipodi:arg1="1.0471976"
       sodipodi:arg2="1.4398967"
       inkscape:flatsided="false"
       inkscape:rounded="0"
       inkscape:randomized="0"
       d="m 299.00707,414.98441 -9.38404,-7.9932 -6.99549,10.1496 -0.98347,-12.28755 -12.12341,2.23029 7.99319,-9.38404 -10.1496,-6.99549 12.28756,-0.98347 -2.23029,-12.12341 9.38404,7.99319 6.99549,-10.1496 0.98347,12.28756 12.12341,-2.23029 -7.99319,9.38403 10.14959,6.99549 -12.28755,0.98348 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want to get the width,height,x,y values
But when it's getting to the foreach there are no results.
I'm trying to extract some data from the xml file content.

Comment: Just a guess without seeing the top of the document, but maybe this is SVG and you need to use the right namespace?

Comment: You should paste complete xml document in a question where you fail to parse one, not just some part of it.

Comment: @smarx right it's svg file. And the file is svg format i posted just another name in my post. Te file is drawing.svg but i'm considering it as xml. I could not find how to parse svg files.

Comment: Try `XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; document.Root.Elements(ns + "rect")...`? (If that's not the right namespace, use the namespace you see at the top of your XML.)

Comment: The namespace in my comment looks right, but now that I see the actual XML, note that there are no `rect` elements as direct children of the root element. You'll need to first get to the `g` element.

Comment: Possibly `document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect")` will take care of that?

Comment: Also, the XML you shared is invalid. There's a "<rect\n<path" in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, you need to use the right namespace to find the elements you're looking for, and since they're not direct children of the root node, you need to use `Descendants` rather than `Elements`. I also changed the `.ToString()` on the attributes to `.Value`, since I assume that's really what you want.

Working code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlParser
{
    public class Test {
        public static void Main(string []args) {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load("test.svg");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

            var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new {
                Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
                Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
                X = e.Attribute("x").Value
            });

            foreach (var item in list) {
                Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}, Height: {1}, X: {2}", item.Width, item.Height, item.X);
            }

            // Output:
            // Width: 45.714287, Height: 30, X: 37.387959
            // Width: 45.714287, Height: 30, X: 91.899246
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following fixed SVG (deleted what appeared to be an extraneous `"<rect"`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg"
   inkscape:export-filename="C:\Users\adili_000\Desktop\drawing.png"
   inkscape:export-xdpi="125"
   inkscape:export-ydpi="125">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="470.51389"
     inkscape:cy="692.09768"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid4172" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4155"
       width="45.714287"
       height="30"
       x="37.387959"
       y="115.30345" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4155-5"
       width="45.714287"
       height="30"
       x="91.899246"
       y="115.40621" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="star"
       style="opacity:1;fill:#f1c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path4841"
       sodipodi:sides="8"
       sodipodi:cx="288.21429"
       sodipodi:cy="396.29076"
       sodipodi:r1="21.58555"
       sodipodi:r2="10.792775"
       sodipodi:arg1="1.0471976"
       sodipodi:arg2="1.4398967"
       inkscape:flatsided="false"
       inkscape:rounded="0"
       inkscape:randomized="0"
       d="m 299.00707,414.98441 -9.38404,-7.9932 -6.99549,10.1496 -0.98347,-12.28755 -12.12341,2.23029 7.99319,-9.38404 -10.1496,-6.99549 12.28756,-0.98347 -2.23029,-12.12341 9.38404,7.99319 6.99549,-10.1496 0.98347,12.28756 12.12341,-2.23029 -7.99319,9.38403 10.14959,6.99549 -12.28755,0.98348 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Working. I need two more parameters to get from the xml. In each rect there is a style with fill and i need to get the color: style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc so i need to get #00c8fc and in some rects there is a transform: transform="matrix(0.9672488,-0.25383017,0.25383017,0.9672488,0,0)" and i need to get the 6 numbers: 0.9672488,-0.25383017,0.25383017,0.9672488,0,0

Comment: And then all this parameters i want to assign to enum. public enum Rects
    {
       FILL, ANGLE, WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y
    }  I'm not sure how to assign the values of each rect to the enum so in the end i will be able to access the enum from another class/script and i will be able to type for example: Rect1.FILL or Rect1.X....then Rect2.FILL or Rect2.WIDTH

Comment: @DanielLip Sounds like you have a couple new questions. Stack Overflow works better if you ask those as new questions rather than comment here.